# full environment for development and production web site

Tags: database, web-development, iis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements)

is there any hosting that gives you full environment for development and production web site 
including IIS,Sql server, SMTP?
Thanks.

Comment: What programming language/technologies do you plan on using?

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this helps, but many hosting companies will let you set up subdomains. I don't know about the windows side, but many, like hostmonster.com will allow you to set up multiple top level or subdomains for $6/month. All of these will have full PHP/MySQL setup, so you could do...

www.livedomain.com // prod
test.livedomain.com // test
dev.livedomain.com // dev

to have an area to code, an area to review before going live, and then a live area. I would think IIS would allow a similar setup to Apache to accomplish this...

Answer (score 0):

Checkout http://www.iis.net/webpi